Why are logs being duplicated in Azure Functions after migrating to .NET 8 Isolated Worker?
I recently migrated my Azure Functions project from .NET 6 In-Process Worker to .NET 8 Isolated Worker and noticed that my logs are being duplicated when running locally and in the Application Insights. For example, when I log a message using ILogger, the same message appears twice in the console.
Environment Details:

Previous Setup: .NET 6, In-Process Worker
Current Setup: .NET 8, Isolated Worker
Azure Functions Core Tools: Version 4.x
.NET SDK: Version 8.0.x
Project Template: Isolated Worker

Project.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="2.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}

Program.cs
 public static IHost BuildPublisher(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
     => hostBuilder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(HostConfiguration)
         .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
         .ConfigureServices(AddServices)
         .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
         {
             logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
             {
                 LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                     == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
                 if (defaultRule is not null)
                 {
                     options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
                 };


             });
         })
         .Build();

...///...


services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(configuration);
services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

Function1.cs
public PlanningSyncFunction(ILogger<PlanningSyncFunction> logger)  
{
    logger.LogDebug("[DEBUG]");
    logger.LogInformation("[INFO]");
    logger.LogWarning("[WARN]");
    logger.LogError("[ERR]");
}

Console Output
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.505Z] Content-Type:application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.506Z]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.514Z] info: Company.Functions.PlanningSyncFunction[0]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.516Z]       [INFO]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.518Z] [INFO]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.522Z] warn: Company.Functions.PlanningSyncFunction[0]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.523Z]       [WARN]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.527Z] [WARN]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.529Z] fail: Company.Functions.PlanningSyncFunction[0]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.529Z]       [ERR]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.532Z] [ERR]
[2024-12-12T10:11:35.560Z] info: Azure.Core[1]


Questions:

Why are logs being duplicated after migrating to .NET 8 Isolated Worker?
Is this due to changes in the default logging behavior of Azure Functions Isolated Worker?
How can I prevent this duplication while keeping proper logging functionality?

Thanks for your help!

You are running locally right?

Yes and also deployed to Azure Functions.


Why are logs being duplicated in Azure Functions after migrating to .NET 8 Isolated Worker?Is this due to changes in the default logging behavior of Azure Functions Isolated Worker?

No duplicates are not sent because of .net 8 Isolated worker.
Below code worked for me where I have used Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider and duplicates are not sent:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var ri_bo = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(cho =>
    {
        cho.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        cho.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        cho.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(rich =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule brch = rich.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (brch is not null)
            {
                rich.Rules.Remove(brch);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, cng) =>
    {
        cng.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hct, rilg) =>
    {
        rilg.AddApplicationInsights(rics =>
        {
            rics.IncludeScopes = true;
        });

        rilg.AddConfiguration(hct.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();

ri_bo.Run();

Function.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace RithApp14
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> rilg;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> varn)
        {
            rilg = varn;

            rilg.LogDebug("[DEBUG] Hello Rithwik Debug");
            rilg.LogInformation("[INFO] Hello Rithwik Info");
            rilg.LogWarning("[WARN] Hello Rithwik Warn");
            rilg.LogError("[ERR] Hello Rithwik Error");
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            rilg.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}

host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.Function1": "Trace",
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}

csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.18.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Output:


Try to follow above steps so that you will not get duplicates and Try to rebuild with above code.

For every function I have, should I set the log level in the host file?
"Function.Function1": "Trace"

You can also use Function : Trace

Why are logs being duplicated after migrating to .NET 8 Isolated Worker?
Is this due to changes in the default logging behavior of Azure Functions Isolated Worker?

No that is not because of migration and your Duplicates issue is solved right? Did you follow the code?

I followed but I would like to understand why this is happening, it's partially answered.

What isnt answered? and what is partially answered? I have given a code which donot create duplicates and said that while migrating there might be some dependencies due to which that might have produced duplicates, so I have said to rebuild the project with mine and I hope it is cleared now

Why the duplication happens, what changed from in-process to isolated level to make it duplicates.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Can you join the discussion link @barruda?
